# JavaFX - Control Item best suited for my needs?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, controls

I want to have a Box which keeps a list of `String` objects. Not a `ChoiceBox`, `ComboBox`, etc because it needs to be displayed without having to click open a Box. The user can add new entries by entering them in a `TextField` below and pressing `Enter`. The control item can't be a `TextField` either because you're not able to click on individual lines of a `TextField`. In this application, I'd like to be able to double click on any item to delete it. If that's really easy, then maybe double click would allow me to edit the entry?

Can anyone here suggest something? Of all the Control types I know of, I cannot think of a single thing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ListView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) with a [`TextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldListCell.html#forListView--). It's rather easy to make those cells editable, since there is already a way to create a cell factory easily using [`TextFieldListCell.forListView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldListCell.html#forListView--)

```
ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>();

// Make cells editable
lv.setEditable(true);
lv.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());

// print selected item to the console
lv.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("Selected Item: "+ newValue);
});

TextField tf = new TextField();
// add new text from the textfield as item to the listview
tf.setOnAction((event) -> {
    lv.getItems().add(tf.getText());
    tf.clear();
});

VBox root = new VBox(lv, tf);
// TODO: add root to scene
```